# How can i get the current element of my mat-table and put in another part of the code?

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-table

I want to pass a current element of a table to another part of the code, like an textarea or an input.

```
<div mat-dialog-content>
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataDetail" class="mat-elevation-z8">

  <ng-container matColumnDef="OriginalCommissionAmount">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Original Commission Amount </th>        
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
      <ng-container *ngIf="element.OriginalCommissionAmount != null; else isEmpty">
        ${{element.OriginalCommissionAmount}}
      </ng-container>
      <ng-template #isEmpty>
        Empty.
      </ng-template>
    </td>       
    </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="LastDatePaid">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Last Date Paid </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
      <ng-container *ngIf="element.LastDatePaid != null; else isEmpty2">
        {{element.LastDatePaid}}
      </ng-container>
      <ng-template #isEmpty2>
        Empty.
      </ng-template>
    </td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="LastAmountPaid">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Last Amount Paid </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
      <ng-container *ngIf="element.LastAmountPaid != null; else isEmpty3">
        ${{element.LastAmountPaid}}
      </ng-container>
      <ng-template #isEmpty3>
        Empty.
      </ng-template>
    </td>
  </ng-container>

    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>

</table>

</div>
```

Out of my mat-table i want to get the {{element.AnotherAttr}}, that is, an attribute of the current element.

```
<textarea>{{element.AnotherAttr}}</textarea>
```

My idea doing this is avoiding another call to the api.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand, how do you know which element you want ? 
You can add a click event on a row and keep the element in an attribute of your component like 'selectedElement'

Comment: Before that, I have another table, and when I click on an element of this table, it returns its details, which opens in dialog form, which is that part of the code that I put into the question. The goal is to place the current element called in an input or text area outside of my mat-table scope for editing. however, I have no idea how to do this, or if there is a way to do it.

Comment: In your datasource dataDetail, you've got many elements right ? So which element to display in another block ?

Comment: {{element.Note}} would be the goal I wanted. Outside of the mat-table

Comment: Yes but which element if you've got a list of it. How do you determine in the list the element to display outside the mat-table ?